# Receive TCP with 2 IP Addresses - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, tcp, ip, ip-address

I'm making a chat program and i have a big problem : I have to make my computer listen more IP Adresses .

I mean that my computer will have to receive TCP data addressed to different IP at the same time .

Example :

the ***Computer 1*** send "Hello 1" to the IP *192.168.1.103* and
the ***Computer 2*** send "Hello 2" to the *IP 192.168.56.1*

My Computer (with IP : **192.168.58.1**) have to receive both the messages ( i think that the only way to do that is to change continuosly my computer IP from 192.168.1.103 to 192.168.56.1 and the other way around)

Yes i know , it's a little hard ...

There's a more simple way to make this ?

Comment: Maybe UDP would be a better fit for you?  https://microchip.wdfiles.com/local--files/tcpip:tcp-vs-udp/TCP_vs_UDP.JPG

Comment: [TcpListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1):

As @tcarvin mentioned, UDP is more advisable. You can use UDP as the initial protocol for a TCP-IP connection and then operate the rest of the chat over TCP-IP after the connection is established.